# Unslider Navigation and Arrows Positioning

Tags: jquery, css, unslider

I'm using [Unslider](http://unslider.com/) and I'm having trouble positioning the arrows and navigation, simply because when they slider is created with jQuery, it adds the nav and arrows outside the div where the slider is being called.

```
<section class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="imgs/banner-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="imgs/banner-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="imgs/banner-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
  </ul>

</section>

<a class="unslider-arrow next"></a>
<a class="unslider-arrow prev"></a>

<nav class="unslider-nav">
  <ol>
    <li data-slide="0">1</li>
    <li data-slide="1">2</li>
    <li data-slide="2">3</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

The nav buttons appear after the `<section>` tag, and so I can't position them so that when the browser resizes the arrows and nav stay in place.

I'm sure it's a simple solution, what am I missing?

Comment: impossible to say without the css

Comment: @damianocelent Thanks but what do you need exactly? Do you want to see the CSS for the plugin or my CSS, I only tried to position the element with absolute positioning (top: 50%) but it doesn't work since the nav element is outside the section element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using owlgraphic.com instead. More flexible with CSS.